# Selectively restricting property access for specific modules

Tags: c#, properties, encapsulation

I have a class `Thing` that is deserialized from a JSON file using `DataContractJsonSerializer`:

```
[DataContract]
class Thing
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // and so on...
}
```

To make this work, all properties need to have `public` or at least `internal` setters.

Two other modules (assemblies) need to access this class:

- `ThingView` should have read-only access to most attributes.
- `ThingEditor` needs full access to all attributes.

I could make the setters `internal` but then the `ThingEditor` would not get full access.

To restrict access for the `ThingView` class, the best idea I could come up with is to create a read-only wrapper of the `Thing` class. But this would involve a lot of code duplication.

Are there better ways to achieve more encapsulation for in a case like this?

(The actual code contains about 20 classes of this type, some of which form nested structures. Also, there are more than two modules that need either read or full access to the properties.)

Comment: Is this a security concern?

Comment: @TheGeneral: Partly yes: Not all users have access to the ThingEditor. But I am more interested in the software design aspect.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing out of the box in the specs that would achieve this. However, you could do something like this for example

```
public interface IReadOnlInterface
{
   int Id { get; }
   string Name { get; }
}

public interface IInterface
{
      int Id { get; set; }
      string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class Thing : IInterface , IReadOnlInterface
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

However there is nothing stopping coders with dirty little fingers casting to the other interface. If its only a runtime issue, then interfaces should be fine. Otherwise youll have to create a better api design with secured data, and proxy type objects with readonly access, Though maybe someone has a better idea.